# Jquery add loading=lazy to all images

Tags: lazy-loading

I have a bigger webpage and it would take days to add the `loading=lazy` attribute to all `img` tags on my site. Is it useful to use something like `$('img'). attr('loading', 'lazy')` (does this work?) to the site, or will it just make the site more slower?

Comment: YES it works and you can speedup your loading speed. Just check your loading speed by something using like www.gtmetrix.com and then add `lazy loader` and then check the speed again. Because I do this and its effective

Comment: Wat type of website are you trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn‘t necessarly have the expected effect - if you‘re adding the attributes via JavaScript, the page itself has already been parsed by the browser and their preloading scripts as well and all of those images would be been put to the download queue, as if the attribute wouldn‘t have existed on them.

So I would heavily recommend to add those attributes within the source code itself already.